# IPad Game Time Manager

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have a game in Ipad that gives out daily rewards, if I advance the date on my device, i'll have a boat load of stuffs, is there a way I can control it? any suggestions on what is the best solution i can implement, even if not best, maybe i need to hear it so i can mixed the ideas and come up with something, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use remote time server to calculate exact periods of time.

Comment: so i guess its just storing the data/info remotely? anything else?

Comment: @paulpolo yes, you're right. The server could send daily rewards to your app so user can't cheat by setting wrong date/time.

Comment: I think this is the most available answer to my question, I'll be accepting this but would still be open for any suggestions/options